# How to get font-family from GitHub server

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

Why not I get the desired result here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<style>
 @font-face
 {
  font-family:'bfont';
  src: url("https://github.com/AIabdoPr/my/blob/master/BLACKANG_1.TTF");
 }

 .title_t_h1
 {
  font-family:'bfont';
  font-size:15pt
 }
 .random_paragraph
 {
  font-family:'bfont';
  font-size:15pt
 }
</style>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Get Font-family from gethub server</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1 class="title_t_h1">
  Title H1 type
 </h1>
 <p class="random_paragraph">
  random paragraph :"jfdnsvnermvnreovnoernvoernvernvenrkvnerllsnvgnesrfdnvmlkensfldnlmvsnbmlnrotbneoibnotrnbortnbortnb"
 </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Where is the error here

I came this way from this site but it did not succeed and the line goes down as normal without change

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the GitHub server you are trying to pull from isn't actually a `.ttf` file. Rather, it is just the repository for the font. The repo name is `BLACKANG_1.TTF` , but this isn't an actual `.ttf` file.

To make this work , download the file from the github link (you can do this by clicking "get raw" or download) then add it to your folder of the site you are making. If it's in the same folder, you would change your code to be :

```
   @font-face {
      font-family: "bfont";
      src: url("./BLACKANG_1.ttf");
    }
```

This should fix the problem you are having of the font not working. Typically when using the `@font-face` it's for a local file. You could also add an `@import` tag to the top of your css, but it still has to be a font file or location, which in this case the URL is only to a github repo.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but I have this font in my computer, and I want to use it to change the text font in my blog on Google Blogger so I uploaded it to the github site and used it, but I didn't get the desired result

Comment: What blog are you using? WordPress? You need to host the font files on your blog, unfortunately the GitHub repo will not work for what you're trying to do.